# Stop jQuery evaluating scripts that have already been executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a history API script that loads new page content without the need for a page refresh. I have come into a problem with inline scripts, where the scripts are evaluated by jQuery even if they have been done so previously. So for example, if someone re-visits a page with an inline script that script will be executed each time they re-visit. This causes problems as say if a DOM element is added in a script than that element will be added several times if they have visited that page several times.

For reasons I won't go into I cannot put these inline scripts into an external file and load them that way.

Here's the coded that deals with the scripts;

```
dom.filter('script').each(function(){//function to allow inline javascript, has to be after page fadeIn incase scripts reference page DOM

    $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
    var script_src = ($(this).attr('src'));

    if (script_src === 'AJAX/request_feed.js' || script_src === 'js/profile.js'){
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
        $.getScript(script_src);
    }

});
```

Should you require any more parts from the whole history script just ask. i don't think they're required though.

**Note:** The if clause is there for a scroll loader i have. I have two scroll_loaders so the scroll event needs to be unbinded and binded each time. No need to worry about that though.

Comment: How exactly do you load the content?  Do you use `.load()`?

Comment: @Pointy I just use an AJAX GET request and retrive content from one div and place it into the page. I have more control this way

Comment: Well then the thing to do is explicitly strip out the `<script>` tags that you don't want evaluated. If you don't, then jQuery will strip them out and then evaluate them.

Comment: @Pointy How can I do this? I realise I would need to put ID's on the script tags but how can I check against ID's that are already executed?

Comment: Well your page framework would need to keep track of the tag "id" values. I think it's a fragile architecture. It'd be much better to isolate the scripts rather than wastefully fetching stuff that your client is going to throw away.

Answer (score 2):

You could store your executed scripts in a cookie, then check the cookie before executing.  One way or another, you'll need some way of keeping track of what has been executed and what hasn't been.

**Alternate Suggestion**

You could tweak your scripts to be self regulating:

myscript.js:

```
(function(){
   if ($(this).parent().script_registry.inArray('myscript')) return false;
   $(this).parent().script_registry.push('myscript');  // Register this script as launched

   alert('Do stuff..');
});
```

Note: The above code may not be 100% syntactically correct.

Comment: I like your thinking. Cookie is not the solution i'm looking for but I had thought about using ID's in the script tag but wasn't sure how to check against loaded in scripts

Comment: I guess I'm not totally grasping your constraints, but I'll throw an alternate suggestion in my answer.

Comment: I didn't know there was such a thing as script_registry. I can't find any quick articles on it? Can you link me to any information on it? Don't worry too much about it though

Comment: What is `script_registry`?

Comment: Just a made-up array to store scripts that have executed.